# change ports on a samba server on a vps

Tags: samba

As is typical, my IPS is blocking samba ports.  I'm trying to setup a samba server that's on the clouds (at rackspace).  How can I:

1) change the ports that samba runs on, i.e. smbd, nmbd on the vps

2) force my samba client on mac os x (default os x Finder connect) to use those ports?

Thanks,

Sam

Comment: I didn't know you could. smb has defined port numbers.  Not sure if they can be overridden.  Intrigued, why run samba on a vps?

Comment: just practice.  plus single sign on for multiple users via ldap & samba that backs-up the profiles to the vps

Comment: @Matt I found out you can do sudo smbd -p 1139 for example.  But even on the vps when I do smbclient -L //localhost I get Connection to localhost:1139 failed (Error NT_STATUS_BAD_NETWORK_NAME)

Comment: Do you have Samba binded to the "lo" interface?

Comment: @Gazzonyx no, why?

Comment: You're in for a world of hurt - use a VPN like everyone else does.

Comment: @SamHammamy I think you have to listen on the local interface to connect to it on localhost.

Answer (score 2):

Like ErikA said, you should be running a VPN for this stuff. Direct Samba connections over the Internet is insane.

I recommend OpenVPN which is available as a supported package for many Linux distributions.

Comment: a VPN wouldn't give me roaming profiles from the login prompt.  Or can I direct the login prompt to authenticate against the VPN

Comment: Use a Linux server as an OpenVPN router and put your Windows system behind it. You're just flat out insane to try and run traffic across the public Internet as if it were wired up in your home office.

Comment: Ok.  So I setup OpenVPN on the Ubuntu VPS, that's great.  But how do I get my OS X Machine to authenticate against it on login, as if it were an Active Directory?

Comment: @SamHammamy at least with Windows clients, [***you can***](http://level2it.wordpress.com/2009/11/05/log-on-using-dial-up-connection-is-gone-in-windows-7/). No idea about OS X. And as already noted by others, changing Samba ports would not enable you to log on as the SMB clients would not allow you to specify an alternate port.

Comment: @syneticon-dj Thanks.  That article is a great help

Comment: @SamHammamy Welcome. BTW: this only works with a VPN connection which could be set up as a DUN entry - i.e. either PPTP (***don't use - [ultimately compromised](https://www.cloudcracker.com/blog/2012/07/29/cracking-ms-chap-v2/)***) or IPSEC/L2TP VPNs. See [here](http://www.jacco2.dds.nl/networking/openswan-l2tp.html) for a Linux-based IPSEC/L2TP setup or preconfigured commercial and OSS alternatives (listing in 1.4).